# How to search in string

Tags: javascript, regex

How to search string with spaces For example:

```
const string = 'This is example message';

string.test('This is example') -> return true. 
string.test('THiS is Example') -> return true
```

I don't want to use `indexOf` because when string has big letters return `false`

Comment: Just use `string.toLowerCase().indexOf()`

Comment: Please use regex for that type of searching

\b(phrase one|phrase two|phrase three|etc)\b

Comment: Shouldn't the last example return false because it contains capital letters?